# Using Inteval Datatype to store result of calculation

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g

I want to create a table which has hiredate and Interval of hiredate and sysdate. How to create a column that automaticlaly stores the calculation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe you can.

The expression you use to create a virtual column [must be *deterministic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions005.htm#BABIGHHI), i.e. always return the same value when called with the same arguments. Involving the current date is fundamentally incompatible with that requirement.

You could use a plain old view though.

```sql
create table mytab (hiredate date);
create view myview
as
 select
   hiredate,
   numtodsinterval(sysdate-hiredate, 'day') delta
 from mytab;

insert into mytab values (to_date('20120101', 'YYYYMMDD'));
commit;
select * from myview;
```

Output:

```
HIREDATE        DELTA
01/01/12    247 9:15:55.0
```

Comment: +1 In the description Oracle Database Error Messages 11g Release 2 (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/e29250.htm#sthref9964) of the following error it is explicitly stated that a deterministic function does not have to depend on the current time: `ORA-30553: The function is not deterministic Cause: ...If it is not deterministic (it depends on package state, database state, current time, or anything other than the function inputs) ...`